# Turn off LEDs on MSI B250I?

Tags: motherboard

I just installed a new motherboard, an MSI B250I. I just noticed after installing that it has some superfluous bright LEDs purely for fashion as it seems (quite unexpected on an Intel B chipset board). I remember from another MSI board that there was an option to turn the LEDs of in the BIOS, back then they were blue, now on the new board they are white.

Comment: I can just tell you how to do it on x470 and that is via the Mystic Light app. Maybe this app is also available for B250l idk.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a hint online and read that there is an MSI "Gaming App" for Windows that should be able to turn off these lights. I downloaded what seemed to be the most recent version, searched the house for a disk with Windows installed, then ran the app which told me that it doesn't work with this platform. Whatever that means.

I looked closely at the [downloads page](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B250I-PRO.html) and found an app called "**MYSTIC LIGHT** User Guide", which is actually a software to control these multicolor lights. Now they are turned off. :)